# Soldering another USB Female Port to existing Female USB Port

Tags: usb, power

I have a device that can give only gives out power to the USB socket, I want to add another USB port onto this but I was wondering if it can do that without affecting performance or without it shorting and breaking the device, I don't want any data to be transfered, just power.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably not. You would need to add the socket to the same buss that has the other sockets and make sure there is adequate power on the buss. Engineers do not typically overengineer USB power ,